# Free LaTeX extension that can be added to flask-ckeditor

Tags: python, web-development, html, text-editor, latex

I also want the LATEX extension to be free in production. Here is the documentation on [https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/>](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/%3E) . I Can use another text editor if someone has a recommendation or even just ckeditor. Just take into consideration I only really know python and flask.